# Disabling CheckBoxes

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

If I have 4 different CheckBoxes and when the user selects one of them I want the other 3 to become disabled so you can't click on a checkbox while another one is already checked how would I go about doing this? I have this, but it doesnt work right now and I thought it would:

```
    If NoDelayCheckMarkBox.Checked = True Then
        timeBetweenIterationDelay = 0
        SecondDelayCheckMarkBox.Enabled = False
        HalfSecondDelayCheckMarkBox.Enabled = False
        FiftyMSDelayCheckMarkBox.Enabled = False
```

I can still click as many check boxes as I want too. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question but if you only want to allow one selection, why not use radio buttons instead?

Comment: I could I didn't even really think about it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? "Only one box checked" should use radio button. "Not allowed to change your mind" should remove (not disable) checkboxes. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @brian already said, Radio buttons seem like a more organic way to achieve this result, but you still could do this with checkboxes if you wanted

Handle the `CheckBox.CheckedChanged` event with the same sub for all four checkboxes

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged
    'cast sender
    Dim senderCheck As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)

    'loop through all checkboxes
    For Each checkbox In {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}

        'only apply changes to non-sender  boxes
        If checkbox IsNot senderCheck Then

            'set property to opposite of sender so you can renable when unchecked
            checkbox.Enabled = Not senderCheck.Checked
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That would leave it possible to uncheck the checkbox without enabling anything else, though. Confusing-ish.